# Easy way to get cmake default compiler

Tags: cmake, g++

I am new to cmake.
I have seen that doing export CXX=g++ tells cmake to use the g++ compiler for the .cpp files for instance. 
I also read that if we don't pass any compiler with CXX, it will search for a compiler with name cc, gcc, cl, bcc, xlc, clang (in that order). But if we don't export any compiler, is there an easy command to know what compiler exactly cmake use for the .cpp files for instance? Will it always be g++ if we have it installed?

Comment: You can get the C and C++ compiler names from the variables
`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`. With the variables `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` you get the identifier of the compiler like GNU, LLVM, or AppleClang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

You can get the C and C++ compiler names from the variables `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` like `gcc`, `g++`, `cl`, or `clang`. With the variables `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` you get the identifier of the compiler like `GNU`, `LLVM`, or `AppleClang`.